# How to change the option values with django-autocomplete-light?

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, django-autocomplete-light

I use django-autocomplete-light in a fairly standard way, simply following the tutorial on http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html.

Whenever I use the Select2 widget, however, the values of the options are automatically the primary keys of the model instances. Is there a way to use set the value to another field of the model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just needed to change the default behavior myself and ran into this, hope it's still going to help someone out there.

The [documentation](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#displaying-selected-result-differently-than-in-list) mentioned the way to return different labels using `get_result_label`

```
class CountryAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_result_label(self, item):
        return item.full_name

    def get_selected_result_label(self, item):
        return item.short_name
```

Now to alter the returned id's, it's very similar. Just overwrite `get_result_value`:

```
def get_result_value(self, result):
    """
    this below is the default behavior, 
    change it to whatever you want returned
    """
    return str(result.pk)
```

In summary, I did something like this:

```
class TagAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):

    def get_result_value(self, result):
        return str(result.name)

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Tag.objects.all()
        if self.q:
            q = self.q
            qs = qs.filter(
                        Q(name__icontains=q)
                    )
        return qs
```